# jQuery how to selected the current list item in a nested list then hide all others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that has 3 list options. Inside each of these list options there is another unordered list that has 2 list options inside.

Inside the unordered list with two options the first list item is an image and the second is a link.

When the user clicks one of the links, I want that current whole group(consisting of the image and the link) to stay showing while the other 2 menu options disappear.

I am having trouble coming up with the right selection.

```js
$('.menu ul>li>ul>li:last-child>a').click(function() {

  var currentLink = $(this);
  var currentGroup = $(this).closest('li').closest('li');
  
  $('.menu ul>li').not(currentGroup).hide();
  
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <!--This is the first link group-->
    <li>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><div class="header"></div></li>
        <li><img src="https://placehold.it/10x10.png"/><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
      </ul>
    <!--This is the second link group-->
    <li>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><div class="header"></div></li>
        <li><img src="https://placehold.it/10x10.png"/><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <!--This is the third link group-->
    <li>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><div class="header"></div></li>
        <li><img src="https://placehold.it/10x10.png"/><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `$('.menu ul>li')` which selects all `li` including the second level one's.

So try

```js
$('.menu ul ul li:last-child > a').click(function() {
  var currentGroup = $(this).closest('.menu > ul > li');

  $('.menu > ul > li').not(currentGroup).hide();

});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <!--This is the first link group-->
    <li>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <div class="header"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.it/10x10.png" /><a href="#">Link One</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--This is the second link group-->
      <li>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <div class="header"></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/10x10.png" /><a href="#">Link Two</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!--This is the third link group-->
      <li>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <div class="header"></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/10x10.png" /><a href="#">Link Three</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```